# how can i add objects from my model to my CBV in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

i am trying to add objects from my model into my CBV, i have a model created so i am trying to pass them to my views, but its not working,tho i have 2 classes created which are Pricing and Pricingservice, i want an inline for a field in Pricingservice which i did, but i dont know how to add both to my view in CBV in the view so as to access them in my template, here is my code below, kindly help me out because i have been battling with this for days, thanks

### model.py

```
class Pricing(models.Model):
    plans = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    amount = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    services = models.CharField(max_length=250)

  
    def __str__(self):
        return self.plans

class Pricingservice(models.Model):
    pricing = models.ForeignKey(Pricing, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    services = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.pricing.plans
```

### admin.py

```
class PricingserviceAdmin(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Pricingservice

@admin.register(Pricing)
class PricingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [PricingserviceAdmin]

    class Meta:
       model = Pricing
```

### views.py

```
class HomePageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'pages/home.html'
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(HomePageView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['Pricing'] = Pricing.objects.all()
        return context
```

### template.html

```
    <div class="row">
     {% for p in Pricing %}
    <div class="col-md-3 ftco-animate">
    
        <div class="pricing-entry pb-5 text-center">
            <div>
                <h3 class="mb-4">{{ p.plans }}</h3>
                <p><span class="price">#{{ p.amount }}</span> <span class="per">/ Month</span></p>
            </div>

            <ul>
                <li>{{ p.services }}</li>
        
            </ul>
    
            <p class="button text-center"><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary px-4 py-3">Get Offer</a></p>
    
        </div>

    
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

[[image: i want to add the pricing services under the price]] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPckX.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
class HomePageView(ListView):
    model = Pricing
    template_name = 'pages/home.html'
```

And then try this template:

```
{% for pricing in object_list %}
    {{pricing.plans}}<br>
    {% for service in pricing.pricingservice_set.all %}
        {{ service.services }}<br>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Please add some styling yourself. :)

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to use a `ListView`. You would need to tell Django what the relevant model for your view is, i.e.:

```
class HomePageView(ListView):
    model = Pricingservice
    template_name = 'pages/home.html'
```

And then in your template, you can use:

```
{% for pricingservice in pricingservice_list %}
{{ pricingservice.pricing }}
{% endfor %}
```

I am not sure exactly how your two models differ, but maybe it would be better to merge them?

Comment: oh thanks for replying,i will try  this now but what do you it mean to merge my two models together?

Comment: @ChosenBrain Is there a good reason to have these models separate? It just looks like it would be better if it was just one model? What error do you get?

Comment: actually i just want to add multiple fields from my admin at a time, thats why i follow the inline

Answer (score 0):

try this

## views.py

```
class HomePageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'pages/home.html'
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(HomePageView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['Pricing'] = Pricing.objects.all()
        return context

class PricePageView(ListView):
    model = Pricingservice
    template_name = 'pages/home.html'
```

### urls.py

```
path('', HomePageView.as_view(), name='home'),
path('price/', PricePageView.as_view(), name='price'),
```

### template.html

```
{% for pricingservice in Pricingservice_list %}
                    <ul>
                        <li>{{ pricingservice }}</li>
                
                    </ul>
                    {% endfor %}
```

am not sure this will work but try this if that answer does not work for you